# How can I convert existing tasks and subtasks to subprojects in Project 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

I understand how to create a subproject and insert the subproject into a master project. Is there a way to take an existing task (and its subtasks) in a master project and convert them to a new subproject?

I do have relationships that cross the boundary of the desired subproject. Cut/pasting the task/subtasks into a new file and inserting that into the master seems undesirable as it will require relinking all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is no way to separate tasks into a new subproject without having to re-link.